# microtime(true) doesn't return correct value in PHP

Tags: php

I want to calculate a query execution time.
This is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);     
$start = microtime(true);  // echo $start would return xxxxxxx.xxxx
$stmt->execute();
$end = microtime(true);
list($usec, $sec) = explode(".", $start);
$timestart = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
list($usec, $sec) = explode(".", $end);
$timeend = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
echo "$timeend - $timestart =".($timeend - $timestart);
```

the result I get from the `echo` command is: `1469612504 - 1469619953 =-7449`
I don't get how `$timeend` is minor than `$timestart`.

What am I doing wrong?
I guess I'm not calculating $timestart and $timeend properly..

Comment: Why are you exploding the float? PHP is quite capable of substracting floats directly.

Comment: `"$timeend - $timestart ="` change to semicolon `'$timeend - $timestart ='` because " colons shows variable that is inside

Comment: @Danielius That's most probably the point.

Comment: so you need to show $timeend - $timestart  or values of them?

Comment: That's basic debugging. See what the variable actually contains.

Comment: You basically add up your micoseconds as seconds. As roberto06 said, just use the floats without splitting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to explode your `$start` and `$end` variables :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);     
$start = microtime(true);  // echo $start would return xxxxxxx.xxxx
$stmt->execute();
$end = microtime(true);
echo "$timeend - $timestart =".($end - $start);
```

Comment: You can also use only one variable, like "player27" mentionen it in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.microtime.php#111107). `$time = -microtime(true); /* do stuff; */ echo 'exec time is ' . microtime(true) + $time`